# How Can i Change the style of my angularjs object?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, object

I don't have that experience to work with json abject  because that i need your help please :( 
I have this object

```
   var obj =    {[
      {
        9 : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        10 : "Berlin",
        Room : "201"
      },
      {
        9 : "Vaffeljernet",
        10: "Århus",
        Room : "204"
      }
    ]
    }
```

What i Need is How can i change the the style of this object to this way of changing

```
   {
201:{9:"Alfreds Futterkiste",10:"Berlin"},
204:{9:"Vaffeljernet",10:"Århus"}
}
```

Comment: First, you need to clarify the object in the first snippet, in its current form it isn't valid.

Comment: No , actually i don't know how can i start to solve this , or what the way  i need to follow , i just need the first way of starting to complete it > >

Comment: no the object which in the first one i took it from console log
i'm sure about it

Comment: Underscore or lodash are very helpful for this type of stuff. any reason in particular you need to change the object to look like that on the front end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a plunker(just JS) :http://plnkr.co/edit/h3EndN8F6milHF2h1gAj?p=preview

```
 var array =    [
      {
        9 : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        10 : "Berlin",
        Room : "201"
      },
      {
        9 : "Vaffeljernet",
        10: "Århus",
        Room : "204"
      }
    ];

  var result = {};

  array.forEach(function(obj) {
    //function runs once for each element in the array, obj = element at current index
    result[obj.Room] = {
      9: obj[9],
      10: obj[10]
    };


  });

  console.log(result);
```

The basics are: [] is an array; {} is an object. In arrays things are identified by their index(0,1,2...). In objects they have keys. So

```
obj = {"201": {'key1':'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}}
```

means you have an object inside which you have another nested object (identified by it's key - 201). The nested object has 2 properties. The first property has a key(key1)  and a value (value1)

```
obj["201"] is {'key1':'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

EDIT:

I suppose you want a more general solution

```
     var newObj ={};
     Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
       if(key !== 'Room') {
         newObj[key] = obj[key];
       }
     });
     result[obj.Room] = newObj;
```

See if you can figure out where to put this

Comment: This makes me want to delete my answer.

Comment: Are you kidding ? is this a solution's ? i'm not that stupid to ask some thing like that -_-  
result[obj.Room] = {
      9: obj[9],
      10: obj[10]
    };

????

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. What do you think is wrong with result[obj.Room] = { 9: obj[9], 10: obj[10] };?

Answer (score 0):

This was a probably a waste of time on my part. But I did learn something along the way. If you arbitrarily reassign an array key(?) to an integer it changes the length? Maybe.

[image: weird array length]

As others pointed out, your object was not valid. I will assume you meant to have an array of objects.

I don't know if '9' and '10' have any significance in being object keys, but thats how I did it before I wanted to light my laptop on fire. Anyways here it is in all its glory: https://jsfiddle.net/v0jetgex/

And yes as ajmajmajma mentioned, lodash helped. alot.

```
var arr = [
    {
        9: "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        10: "Berlin",
        Room: "201"
    },
    {
        9: "Vaffeljernet",
        10: "Århus",
        Room: "204"
    }
];

var newArr = [];
var newerArr = [];

_.each(arr, function (obj) {
    var room = _.result(_.pick(obj, "Room"), "Room");
    var nine = _.result(_.pick(obj, "9"), "9");
    var ten = _.result(_.pick(obj, "10"), "10");
    newArr.push(room);
    newerArr.push({
        '9': nine,
        '10': ten
    });
});

var groups = _.groupBy(newArr, function (a, b) {
    return a.replace(/\s+/g, '');
});

_.toArray(groups).forEach(function (group, index) {

    _.extend(group, {
        '9': _.result(newerArr[index], '9'),
        '10': _.result(newerArr[index], '10')
    });

    delete group[0];
});

console.log('groups', groups);
```